# Scraping the names of the accounts who liked a post on Instagram, using Python and Selenium, but only 11 names returned

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to scrape the names of the accounts who liked a post on Instagram, using Selenium and Python.

https://www.instagram.com/p/B57dJp3gIGw/

There was no error returned, and I successfully scraped, but only the top 11 names of those who liked the post returned, while 40 persons liked the post. I am wondering what the reason is, and how I can fix it?

```
liker_list = []
likers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("qyrsm")

for n in likers:
    #scrape the name of the likers
    liker = n.find_element_by_class_name("_4EzTm").get_attribute("textContent")
    liker_list.append(liker)


print(liker_list)
```

Here is the result(the liker_list)

```
['rycmtn', 'asat0oo', 'misswanderwolf', 'renkuga0202', 'na_na972', 'natsu_5550', 'hachibayinternational_inc', 'mi.kyoung.jeon', 'crane42195', 'michi___kusa', 'ankhcarpediem']
```

Comment: This is lacking information. Please include **all** relevant code and data, as well as an explanation of what you have done to try to solve this. See: [mcve], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: you have to check in html if other items use the same class name. Pages may use random names for classes to stop bots and script.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the page needs to be scrolled down to view all likes and scrape them.

The chunk to scroll infinetly is below, and you can add what you have to the inside of this loop to scrape the data while it scrolls.

```
def scroll():

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
scroll()
```

You will add your code after the time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME) line.

Hope this helps.